# Extension Maintenance: Settings

Tags: extension

It's time to update the Phone Number Validator to support version 4.7.

In the uninstall function, I tidily remove the settings that get added during install. This looks as follows:

'DELETE FROM civicrm_setting WHERE group_name = "com.civifirst.phonenumbervalidator"'

But the group_name field has been removed. How can we neatly remove settings entries in a way that supports 4.6 and 4.7?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

The `group_name` in <=v4.6 was deceptive -- in some circumstances, it provided namespacing, but it in others it didn't, so the safe play has always been to use some kind of name-prefixing.

If the setting names are prefixed, then do something like:

```
DELETE FROM civicrm_setting WHERE name LIKE "phonenumbervalidator_%"
```